Can I control 2 circuits with a single on/off switch?
I have a maintained contact pushbutton (on/off states) which should be used to control two light circuits, the low and the high beam circuits. Is it possible to build such a (SP3T) switch using relays in order to control both the states of these lights in an on/on/off configuration?
In other words when I press the button once, the low beam circuit should activate, when I press it again the low beam deactivates and the high beam activates. When I press it a third time the lights turn off.
Thanks for the help!

You can do it with Johnson Counter like 4017 chip.

An on/off maintained switch + three states...how do you feel about a microcontroller?

Do you want to use mechanical relays?

Yes if possible I'd like to use mechanical relays. I'm trying to avoid using a microcontroller or something, because it's just a circuit in a car.

Do the 3 state shifting reliable with just relays is a challenge. It’s possible with caps but there can appear many malfunctions in case of short button press vs. long button press, i.e.

I have simulated a circuit (short-term link: https://tinyurl.com/2ob2v8ue) that can do this with a little bit of discrete logic (a quad D flip-flop and an XOR), a few resistors, a capacitor and a couple of relays.  This way you could use high-voltage discrete logic ICs, which could use the 6V/12V supply direct from the car for power.  The switch is debounced (you have to click and hold on it for a wee bit to get it to switch, and then give it a wee break before it can be switched again).  A real-life circuit would probably require some diodes and maybe more capacitors.
